# Find the maximum consecutive years for each ID's in a table(Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to solve a problem of how to find the maximum count of consecutive years in a series of records. In the following example:

```
ID  Year
1 1993
1 1994
1 1995
1 1995
1 2001
1 2002
2 1993
2 1995
2 1996
2 1996
2 1998
2 1999
2 2000
2 2001
2 2001
```

My result set should look like

```
id   count
1      3
2      4
```

I have to write the code in oracle SQL.

Comment: Please Use SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a recursive CTE, where each iteration matches a row with the row for the prior year. Not sure how that looks in Oracle, though, so I'll just leave it as a comment that might help someone else with an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will produce your desired result:

```
select
  id,
  ayear,
  byear,
  yeardiff
from
(
  select
    a.id,
    a.year ayear,
    b.year byear,
    (b.year - a.year)+1 yeardiff,
    dense_rank() over (partition by a.id order by (b.year - a.year) desc) rank
  from
    years a
    join years b on a.id = b.id 
        and b.year > a.year
  where
    b.year - a.year = 
      (select count(*)-1
         from years a1
        where a.id = a1.id
             and a1.year between a.year and b.year)
)
where
  rank = 1
```

**EDIT** updated to display start/end years of longest stretch.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b8ca/54/0)

Comment: This is amazing response..though I still have to understand the code(am new to sql)..But i really really appreciate you for your time on this. Thanks a lot JOE.

Comment: Hi Joe, I have duplicate rows in my actual data set. And this code doesn't seem to work in that case. Could you please help me with a modified version of your code that can also address duplicate row..(Note: I modified the test data in the main question)

Comment: Sure, just change: "(select count(*)-1"  to "(select count(distinct year)-1"

Comment: No problem.  I updated my original answer above to reflect the change.

Comment: Hi Joe, is there a way I can also display the years used to calculate the year diff in this query? Thanks in advance. -AVG

Comment: Do you mean you want to see all of the years that make up the longest stretch?

Comment: not all years but just the start and end of that stretch. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
with cte as
(select t.id, t.year, d.d, row_number() over (partition by t.id, d.d 
                                              order by t.year) rn
 from (select -1 d from dual union all select 1 d from dual) d
 cross join my_table t 
 where not exists
       (select null
        from my_table o
        where t.id = o.id and t.year = o.year-d.d) )
select s.id, max(e.year-s.year)+1 year_count
from cte s
join cte e on s.id = e.id and s.rn = e.rn and e.d=1
where s.d=-1
group by s.id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b644/10).

Comment: Hi, I am looking for a solution with out CTE..most likely with the use of flags. This is because I am trying to build a SAP web intelligence report using this SQL..and solution with flags would be very helpful for me

Comment: But I really appreciate your quick response MARK.

Comment: @user2283660: Why would the use of a SAP web intelligence report preclude CTEs? What do you mean by "flags"?

Comment: I came across a solution..where flags are used to achieve the desired result..but unfortunately it was written in SQL server and is not good for oracle. Source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic10547-8-1.aspx?Update=1 . Sorry If i've confused you. Thanks

Comment: @user2283660: The `d` column in the CTE acts in a similar way to the `flag` column in the linked example. You still haven't explained why you can't use a CTE in a SAP web intelligence report.

Comment: To be frank I am not sure if I can use CTE in the custom SQL of SAP web intelligence tool(am new to both SQL and Web Intelligence). So am looking for a traditional approach for this.

Comment: Please enlighten me if my assumptions are wrong. Am open to suggestions. Thanks MARK.

Comment: @user2283660: I don't know - I haven't used the SAP web intelligence tool, so I don't know what restrictions it has. From what you were saying, it sounded as though you were certain that it couldn't use CTEs; I wondered why this would be the case.

Comment: But I did search for its use in the tool in the major SAP forums..I couldn't find any, so i just assumed that i can't use it in the tool. Can you please suggest(any good books, forums) me some ways to improve my sql skills. thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

with t1 as
(
select
id,
year,
lead(year) over(partition by id order by year) as nxt_yr
from tree
),
t2 as
(
select
id,
year,
nxt_yr,
nxt_yr - year as diff
from t1
),
t3 as
(select
id,
year,
nxt_yr,
diff,
lag(diff) over(partition by id order by year) as diff_lag,
lead(diff) over(partition by id order by year) as diff_lead
from t2
)
select id, sum(diff) + 1
from t3
where ((diff = 1) and (diff_lag = 1)) or ((diff = 1) and (diff_lead = 1))
group by id

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to use better formatting for your answers and explain why this answers the given question.